# Write a program that will ask the user for the number of tickets and output total

Tags: java, boolean, output, println

Write a program that will ask the user for the number of adult tickets, the number of children’s tickets, whether they want reserve or general admission, and whether they have a radio voucher to use.  Calculate the cost of the order.

There are two levels of tickets, Reserved for $55.00 each or General Admissions at $35.00 each.  Kids under 12 are half off. 
    The local radio station is running a special.  If you call in, they will send you a voucher that will give you a 20% discount.

All orders over $200 get a 10% discount on the final price (after other discounts are applied) and those over $400 get 15% off.

My code so far...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // variables
    int adultTix;
    int childTix;
    int GENERAL_ADMISSION = 35;
    int RESERVED = 55;
    double radioDiscount = .20;
    double ticketTotal = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many adult tickets?");
    adultTix = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many kids tickets?");
    childTix = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Reserved tickets are $55 each and General Admission is $35."
                    + " Would you like Reserved or General Admission? (enter GA or RE only):");
    String tixType = scan.nextLine();
    if (tixType == "GA" || tixType == "ga") 

        ticketTotal = ((adultTix * GENERAL_ADMISSION) + ((childTix * GENERAL_ADMISSION) / 2));
    else if (tixType == "RE" || tixType == "re")
        ticketTotal = ((adultTix * RESERVED) + ((childTix * RESERVED) / 2));

    System.out.println("Do you have a radio voucher? (enter yes or no):");
    String radioQ = scan.nextLine();

    if (radioQ == "yes")
        System.out.print("With the radio discount, you will save 20%!");
         if (radioQ == "no")
            System.out.println("No radio discount.");

         double radioT;
    radioT = ((ticketTotal - (ticketTotal * radioDiscount)));
    if (radioT >= 200 && radioT < 400)
        System.out.println("With a 10% discount, your total is: $"
                + (radioT * .9));
    else if (radioT > 400)
        System.out.println("With a 15% discount, your total is: $"
                + (radioT * .85));
    scan.close();
}
```

}

Asks all of the questions correctly but doesn't return an output. This is a simple Java program so I would like the simplest answer possible

Comment: Please see [How do I compare Strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- When testing for equality amongst objects, you should always use equals method and now "==" which means you are comparing two object reference. So change the following from

  if (tixType == "GA" || tixType == "ga")

With

```
if (tixType.equalsIgnoreCase("ga"))
```

Same for other string comparison.

- After asking for whether user has radio voucher or not, you should then only do calculation related to radio voucher like:

  ```
  if (radioQ == "yes")//use equalsIgnoreCase method of String
     System.out.print("With the radio discount, you will save 20%!");
     radioT = ((ticketTotal - (ticketTotal * radioDiscount)));
     if (radioT >= 200 && radioT < 400)
         System.out.println("With a 10% discount, your total is: $"
          + (radioT * .9));
     else if (radioT > 400)
         System.out.println("With a 15% discount, your total is: $"
           + (radioT * .85));
     //apply discount on ticket total?
  } else ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that none of your `if`s and `else`s are firing correctly because you're comparing your strings incorrectly.

Instead of `if (str == "value")` you need `if (str.equals("value"))` everywhere. In cases where you want a case-insensitive match like `if (str == "value" || str == "VALUE")` you need `if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("value"))` instead.

Please check out [How do I compare Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1237040) for more info